# how to calculate avarage variance and avarage covariance

Tags: portfolio-management

I would like to figure out how to calculate `av.variance` and `av.cov`.

I know how to calculate portfolio variance( for large portfolio),

```
var(p)=1/n avarage variance+(1-1/n)avarage covariance,
```

If we have a pair of correlation of five asset and standard deviation of each five asset, how are we going to calculate `avarage covariance` and `avarage variance` so that we can put the data in above formula?

It confuse me because some questions `avarage covariance` and `avarage variance` are given.

thanks,i  got you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$w$ is a vector of portfolio weights.

Portfolio variance $Var(r_p)$ is:

$$Var(r_p) = w^T V w$$ where $V$ is your asset variance-covariance matrix.

Let me know if this helps: in theory $w = 1/n$ where $n$ is the number of assets should lead to some sort of "average" covariance even if I think "averages" do not really apply to this context.